# How to convert 10^4 to binary

Tags: math, binary, decimal, computer-science

I need to convert 10^4 to binary

expanding it will give me a large number and dividing that by 2 a bunch of times will be really inefficient

```
10^4 = 10000
```

how do i do it directly

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not related to programming

Comment: @Nico, i guess i can ask computer science questions here,
hence the tag with 9.2K watchers

Comment: What language do you want to implement this in?

Comment: Converting a number to a binary is no related to computer science, that's pure math

Comment: Internally, the number is already in binary; "division by 2" is just a bit shift, which is *extremely* efficient. The question is, do you want an ASCII string like "10011100010000", or a list like [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], or something else?

Comment: @chepner
its not a programming question, you can go ahead and vote to close it,
i could not find it being answered anywhere so i asked it here,
still if anyone can find an answer to this please let me know, 
ill go from there

Comment: @chepner say i want an ASCII

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a recursive function, the pseudo-code is here:

```
int Convert_to_binary (x):
     if(x == 0):
        return 1;
     if(x == 1):
        return 10;
     if(x%2 == 1):
        return Convert_to_binary(x-1)+1;
     if(x%2 == 0):
        return Convert_to_binary(x/2)*10;
```

This will return the binary format as an integer like 2 is 10 in binary and 1 is 1
in binary format and 3 is 11 and so on

Answer (score 0):

There is a quick method to convert decimal number to binary form,

```
   0^2 = 1 
   1^2 = 2
   2^2 = 4
   2^3 = 12
   2^4 = 16
   2^5 = 32
   2^6 = 64
   2^7 = 128
   2^8 = 256
   2^9 = 512
   2^10 = 1024
   2^11 = 2048
   2^12 = 4096
   2^13 = 8192
   2^14 = 16384
```

Since we want to find binary of 10000, we can stop at 2^13. The number 13 means that the binary of 10000 is 14 bit long(0-13).

1000 - 8192 = 1808

so we next want to find the number's that sum up to 1808 from the 2^0  to  2^10 (2^10<1808). it's not difficult to find whch are those numbers from the table

```
2^10 = 1024
2^9 = 512
2^8 = 256
2^4 = 16

1024+512+256+16 = 1808
```

That means in the binary form of the decimal number 10000 only the 13, 10, 9, 8, 4 bit position's are '1' other bit position's are '0'.

so the binary of 10000 is,

````
       ```
            10011100010000
        ```
````

It's easy to remember the above table so we don't need to use the very basic
tedious method to convert a decimal number to binary form.

Comment: @user15964105 i don't know this is the answer you looking for, i wrote this answer coz i thought you were trying to find is there any other way to convert decimal to binary convertion other than the very fundmental method of repeated divison.